# What are the exact angles of the triangular faces of each of the rhombic pyramids of the icosahedron stellation, the compound of five octahedra?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I'm talking about this [compound of five regular octahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_five_octahedra). Based on looking at the icosahedron stellation diagram and making an educated guess about where the golden ratio comes in, I calculated the angles as$ $
$\theta, \frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{2\pi}{3}-\theta$
where$ $
$\theta = \frac{\pi}{3} + 2 \arctan( \frac{\sqrt{5} - 2}{\sqrt{3}})$$, $
but am not confident I am right — thought it was weird it didnt reduce to a closed form solution.

Comment: Wikipedia notes that adding these pyramids to the rhombic triacontahedron, "[...] does not generate the **regular** compound of five octahedra, but shares the same topology and can be smoothly deformed into the regular compound" (emphasis mine). If that's the case, can't you add pyramids of any height you like, meaning the angles needn't be anything in particular?

Comment: The compound is one of the stellations of the icosahedron. I believe the actual stellation is exactly a compound of five regular octahedra.  My reading of the note in wikipedia is that it is *not* exactly a rhombic triacontahedron augmented with pyramids on the faces in that, I am guessing, the actual pyramids do not have flat bases -- they are just close to flat but are actaully bent slightly along the short axis of the golden rhombs that make a rhombic triaqcontahedron. Someone correct m,e if I am wrong please.